# how to increase font size of number as number increases?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am using [react-countup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countup) to "count up" to a value. A user clicks a button, they generate the value 9.57, and using react-counter, the value increases from 1.00 to 9.57 visually over a period of time.

Code:

```
const { start } = useCountUp({
    ref: countUpRef,
    start: 1.00,
    end: val[rand],
    decimals:2,
    decimal:".",
    onReset: () => setRand(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)),
  });

return (
    <VStack>
        <Text ref={countUpRef} fontSize={val[rand] * 20} /> 
        <Button
            backgroundColor="#BB86FC"
            borderRadius="25px"
            _hover={{
                bg: '#121212'
            }}
            _active={{
                bg: '#121212'
            }}
            onClick={start}
        >
            New Value
        </Button>
    </VStack>
)
```

Is it possible to increase the size of the text component dynamically as the number increases during the animation from 1.00 to 9.57?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. The way this hook is structured you give it a ref which the hook uses to directly set the content of the element. This means that the hook does not provide to you the current value at that spot of the animation.

Answer (score 1):

The API docs mentions [`onUpdate`](https://github.com/glennreyes/react-countup/tree/dfbf8f5f2d5f86fb1064af10bb78ec2afc56cd14#onupdate--pauseresume-reset-start---void) combining this with react hooks allows us to use state to trigger changes by incrementing the fontSize value.

Using this code

```js
const [fontSize, setFontSize] = useState(10);

const onUpdate = () => {
    setFontSize(fontSize + 1)
}

const { start } = useCountUp({
    ref: countUpRef,
    start: 1.00,
    end: val[rand],
    decimals: 2,
    decimal: ".",
    onReset: () => setRand(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)),
    onUpdate, // can be expanded to onUpdate: onUpdate
});
```

You can then set your style. I'm using inline style here for simplicity's sake  but there more elegant solutions to styling.

````js
return (
    <VStack>
        <Text
            ref={countUpRef}
            fontSize={val[rand] * 20}
            style={{ fontSize } } // set font size here 
        />
        <Button
            backgroundColor="#BB86FC"
            borderRadius="25px"
            _hover={{
                bg: '#121212'
            }}
            _active={{
                bg: '#121212'
            }}
            onClick={start}
        >
            New Value
        </Button>
    </VStack>
)
)```
````

Comment: I added a link to the docs